# Regex: Parsing after 16 occurrences of a character?

Tags: php, regex, character, explode

/* Edited to make sense! */

I 900 lines of this:

```
;745;ref;name;Adress;zipcode;;mobphone;;;;;;;;;
```

i want 900 lines of this:

```
array(
  '',
  745,
  'ref',
  'name',
  'adress',
  'zipcode',
  '',
  'mobphone'
  etc..
)
```

Some of the lines appear to be concated to one, so it's one long instead of two short. I need to use PHP's split() function to split the lines after every 16th semicolon character, that's what i need your help with.

Comment: @querty: Please describe exactly the input and output per line. Do you expect an array `[(empty), 745, ref, name, Adress, zipcode, (empty), mobphone, (empty), (empty),...]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will help you, but PHP already contains functionality which allows you to parse a CSV file.  The [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) function will read a CSV file line by line.  It returns an array containing the values of each field in the current row.

In your case, you would need to tell it to use a semi-colon instead of a comma as the field delimiter.

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
while ($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ';')){
  $firstField = $line[0];
  $secondField = $line[1];
  //...
}
```

Comment: @qwerty Actually, I think this is exactly what you are looking for.  I was lazy and didn't read the entire question--I just saw "CSV" and "split()" and thought that I'd suggest "fgetcsv()" to you.

Comment: Haha, well you were right! I was expecting the same error but this actually worked! Much more reliable than using split() or explode(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at explode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: I used explode() before and parsed it at every line break, but it didn't work as expected. I need to use split(), but i need help with the regex..